# Dynamically allocating an array of struct pointers, pointing them and qsort-ing them

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I've been googling and trying to do this all day but with no success. There are other topic with similar problems but I can't seem to make it work.

This is the code:

```
void sort_structs_example(Stock **head, int count)
{
    Stock **toSort = NULL;

    int i;

    memLoc(&toSort, sizeof(toSort)*count);

    for (i = 0; count > 0 && i < count && (head != NULL); i++)
    {
        if (i == 0) toSort[0] = *head;
        else
        {
            toSort[i] = toSort[i - 1]->next;
        }
    }

    qsort(toSort, count, sizeof(Stock), struct_cmp_by_product);

    for (i = 0; count > 0 && i < count && (head != NULL); i++)
    {
        printColor(-1, i, toSort[i]->name, 'G', 'B');
    }

    system("pause");
    free(toSort);
}

int struct_cmp_by_product(const void *Ap, const void *Bp)
{
    Stock A = *(Stock *)Ap;
    Stock B = *(Stock *)Bp;
    return strcmp((&A)->name, (&B)->name);
}
```

Stock is a struct with a variable "name" and "next" in it.
parameter "count" receives the number of current Stock structures.
parameter **head is a pointer the last added Stock, and I access other Stocks by going (*head)->next , it's a linked structure.

This is memLoc:

```
int memLoc(void **var, int size)
{
    if (NULL == (*var = malloc(size)))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else return 1;
}
```

So I think I amn't using memLoc right and something in the qsort condition is messed up but I got tangled in all the pointers. Help please? Thanks.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: Break this down into single issues.  Using a debugger will help at this point, because as written, the snippets you have provided will not make it through compile.  You will get warnings and errors.

Answer (score 1):

I can't offer a solution but I can see you are getting tangled in your pointers. In `struct_cmp_by_product()` you have copied the struct values to local variables and then used them as pointers.

```
return strcmp((&A)->name, (&B)->name);
```

Would be better using the local structures directly

```
return strcmp(A.name, B.name);
```

Even better would be this, which recasts the pointer types (not what they point to).

```
int struct_cmp_by_product(const void *Ap, const void *Bp)
{
    return strcmp( ((Stock *)Ap)->name, ((Stock *)Bp)->name );
}
```

The reason this is better is because `Stock` might be a very large structure, and it's not necessary to make local copies.